# Output List of User's Groups

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, script

While easy on Linux, not as easy on Windows from what I've been able to gather so far. I've found the command that kinda does what I want which is:

```
net user username /domain
```

However I wish to strip all of the data except for the list of the groups. I think findstr may be the answer but I'm not sure of how to use this to do that. Essentially, I guess the script would do something like this (unless there is a more specific command which would be fabulous):

```
net user username /domain > temp.txt
findstr (or some other command) file.txt > groups.txt
del temp.txt
```

The output of the data would be a list like this:

group1; group2; group3

Now, I could be going about this a complicated way, so as I mentioned if there is a command that can output ONLY a user's security groups that would be fantastic.

Comment: Is writing a custom tool in [Python](https://gist.github.com/b03679506faee81974b6) or C# acceptable?

Comment: That's beyond my capabilities but if you can get me something that I can compile and execute I'd certainly be very thankful :)

Comment: This isn't something you'd normally want to do in Windows.  Can you explain why you want the output in this particular format?  We may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Take a look at this Stack Overflow thread: [How to get all groups that a user is a member of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5072996)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dsquery user -name "My Full Name" | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid
```

I found this pretty much gives me what I was looking for, in case anyone was curious! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use PowerShell!

```
$user = [wmi] "Win32_UserAccount.Name='JohnDoe',Domain='YourDomainName'"
$user.GetRelated('Win32_Group')
```

or only for group names:

```
$user = [wmi] "Win32_UserAccount.Name='JohnDoe',Domain='YourDomainName'"
$user.GetRelated('Win32_Group') | Select Name
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/67defa12-6ad1-439b-bd11-3abfc5b5208a/

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.

```
net user paul /domain | find "Global Group memberships"
```

Will give you the the groups, but if you don't want the header you'd need something more involved:

```
for /f "tokens=4*" %f in ('net user paul /domain ^| find "Global Group memberships"') do echo %f
```

So %f contains the groups.

Comment: Thanks, that kinda looks like what I'm after but the first example only outputs data from that line, if there are say a dozen groups, most won't show and the second example you gave is giving me the error "f was unexpected at this time" from what I gather, it's not liking the final "%f", I'm just a beginner with these batch scripts :)

Comment: If you use it in a script, you need to use %%f.  Yes, good point, the output will wrap and get lost.  Do you have an output you can paste, I don't have the right setup to test.  It may need something more robust than hacking bits out of the ```net user``` command :)

Comment: Hmm.. won't let me edit my comment, anyways: From my VM machine, the output of `net user username / domain` is essentially the same as my work one. A copy of it can be found [here](http://justpaste.it/iwg)